# How to prevent .gradle folder from being deleted on mac

Tags: android, macos, flutter, android-studio, gradle

My .gradle folder in my home directory sometimes deleted. So, everytime I have to build my Android project, it will redownload. It's hurts because I have slow and limited internet quota.

How to prevent .gradle and other project dependencies from being deleted?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That...really should not be happening.  Do you know what's deleting it?

Comment: I do not know. The only possibility I can think of is the CleanMyMac app. But I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Finally I found what's removes it,
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/92469

Answer (score 1):

You can move your .gradle folder in safe location and select that new location by using below option in android studio.

[image]

Comment: Finally I found what's removes it,
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/92469